# Show that if $\langle Tx,x\rangle \geq 2\left\| x \right\|^2$, then $T$ has dense image

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

**Exercise:**

Let $H$ be an inner product space and $T:H \to H$ be a linear operator, such that:
$$\langle Tx,x\rangle \geq 2\left\| x \right\|^2, \quad \forall x \in H.$$
Show that $T$ has dense image.

**Discussion:**

My initial thought was working with the given condition in order to construct an expression, such as for all $x \in H$ and $\varepsilon >0$, $y \in H$ it holds: $\left\| Tx - Ty \right\| < \varepsilon$. Then the image space spanned by the operator would be dense.

I tried working around with Cauchy Scwarz, yielding:

$$\left\| Tx\right\|\left\|x\right\| \geq \left| \langle Tx, x\rangle \right| \geq 2\left\|x\right\|^2 \implies \left\|Tx\right\| \geq 2\left\|x\right\|, \quad \forall x \in H.$$

Then, since $T$ is linear, let $x:= x-y \in H$ and:

$$\left\|Tx - Ty\right\| \geq 2 \left\|x-y\right\|$$

By the Triangle Inequality, we can write:

$$\left\|Tx \right\| + \left\|Ty\right\| \geq\left\| Tx - Ty\right\| \geq 2\left\|x-y\right\|$$

I don't know if that helps though.

I know that by the condition given, we can easily show that the operator is $"1-1"$ - not sure if that can help though.

Any hints or help will be appreciated!

Comment: Is $H$ complete?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy No, only condition given is that $H$ is an inner product space.

Comment: Neither is $T$ given to be continuous, is that right?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon This is an exercise from an undergrad Functional Analysis course that mostly works with Bounded Linear Operators (thus continuous) - but in this exercise there is no boundedness - continuity implied, thus I guess we can not assume as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $y \perp \mathcal{R}(T)$. Then
$$
         0 = \langle Ty,y\rangle \ge 2\|y\|^2 \ge 0 \implies y=0.
$$

Comment: So straightforward and despite that I was trying to build expressions, that forgot the $\bot$ theorem. Thanks!

Comment: @Rebellos : You're welcome.